# Find the smallest set of connected substrings

Tags: string, algorithm, set

Let's consider a query set Q and a larger superset S. Each element of Q exists in S. The goal is to express Q using the smallest number of (connected) "components" of S.

Here is a concrete example:
Q={I love France and wine}
S={(I live here), (I love you and her), (France is beautiful), (cheese and wine)}

A solution for Q might:
- "I" from "I live here"
- "love" from "I love you and her"
- "France" from "France is beautiful"
- "and" from "I love you and her"
- "wine" from "cheese and wine"
This results in 5 "components", i.e. "I", "love", "France", "and", "wine"

A better solution is:
- "I love" from "I love you and her"
- "France" from "France is beautiful"
- "and wine" from "cheese and wine"
This results in 3 "components", i.e. "I love", "France", "and wine"
which might be the optimal solution for this example. We want to minimize this number of "components".

Is there anyone who knows how such algorithm is called?
I searched in text parsing, text mining and so on but I did not find anything appropriate.

Comment: If Q=(a b a) and S={(a), (b)}, does the unique solution have two or three components?

Comment: Are Q and the elements of S sets, or are they sequences?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like the [set cover problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), in which you have a master set (in your case, the query) and a family of sets (your components) to pick from with the goal of covering every element of the master set.  This problem is well studied, but unfortunately it's NP-hard and there is no known polynomial-time algorithm for it.  Moreover, the best polynomial-time approximation algorithms for set cover only get within a factor of O(log n) of the true solution in the worst case.

If you're dealing with small queries or small numbers of components, you can just brute-force the answer by listing all subsets and checking which ones work.  For large queries or large numbers of components, though, you should not expect to get exact answers efficiently.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not exactly classical set cover since that amounts to finding a subset of S. The OP's required solution isn't such a subset.

Comment: @larsmans- I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: For set cover, the elements of the solution must be elements of S, but the OP wants subsets of elements of S. Also, the universe should be the union of S, so that should be {I live here love you and her France is beautiful cheese wine}.

Comment: @larsmans- Perhaps I'm mistaken, but if you filter out all words from each of the components that aren't in the original sentence, doesn't this reduce to the original problem?

Comment: Yes, I guess so, assuming the OP actually deals with sets instead of strings/sequences (see the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would describe this problem as "minimum interval cover"; I'm not sure that's the canonical name, but I'm not the first to use that phrase.

There's an efficient algorithm that has two phases. In the first phase, identify the maximal substrings of the query that appear in the source. For each such substring, output an interval for the second phase. In the second phase, find a minimum-cardinality cover by choosing repeatedly the interval with the highest endpoint that covers the lowest uncovered position.

In your example

```
Q=(I love France and wine)
S={(I live here), (I love you and her), (France is beautiful), (cheese and wine)}
```

the intervals are, indexing from one, (1, 2) "I love", (3, 3) "France", (4, 5) "and wine". Oops, now the second phase is trivial. Suppose instead

```
Q=(a b c d)
S={(a b), (b c), (c d)}
```

then the intervals are (1, 2) "a b", (2, 3) "b c", (3, 4) "c d". The lowest uncovered is 1; we take (1, 2). The lowest uncovered is 3; we take (3, 4) over (2, 3) because 4 > 3.

Edited to add:

The bottleneck is likely to be the first phase. If it's a problem, there's an algorithm for that: construct a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) containing the source sentences. Then, traverse the tree according to the query string. Unless the query appears verbatim in the source, you'll eventually try to follow a nonexistent link; in that case, the current maximal interval ends, and you need to follow the suffix links until you can make progress again. (Computational biologists, which algorithm am I describing?)